# How to insert into a table with a column named 'when' and 'user'

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to programmatically insert a row/record into a table *(generated by third party software)* where one of the fields is named `when` and `user` which are coincidentally sql keywords.

The sql command is:

```
INSERT INTO APPT 
(ApptID,Type,Descrip,When,Flag,User,DTS) 
VALUES 
(41,0,'Test Note','20/10/2014 1:42:00 PM',16,'AP','22/10/2014 8:24:01 AM')
```

Which gives the errors:

```
Error 156: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'When'.
Error 156: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'.
```

Comment: Simple solution:  Don't use reserved words for column or table names.  Instead, consider something like `UserId` and `ApptDate`.

Comment: well... sometimes you do not have control over the schema

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To escape reserved keywords in the name of a column (or table), put the name of the column in square brackets:

```
INSERT INTO APPT (ApptID,Type,Descrip,[When],Flag,[User],DTS)
```

Answer (score 2):

All the SQL keywords should be kept within the square brackets.

```
INSERT INTO APPT 
(ApptID,Type,Descrip,[When],Flag,[User],DTS) 
VALUES 
(41,0,'Test Note','20/10/2014 1:42:00 PM',16,'AP','22/10/2014 8:24:01 AM')
```